# nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, slather

I am setting up `Fastlane` with `Slather`.

The slather step is failing with

```
[13:55:11]: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

running `ruby -v` I get

```
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "setting up" What do you mean by "the slather step"? How may I attempt to **reproduce** your problem?

Comment: Are you doing something with `gem install`? Or with `bundle`? Are you using `rbenv`, `rvm`, or similar? (Why might the system be reporting multiple ruby versions?)

Comment: This is the same error I have got while running the unit test case using the fastlane.
`fastlane [platform_name] tests`. @Harry Did you get the solution to your problem?

Comment: @KamarShad i had the same issue and found a solution, maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775795/fastlane-nokogiri-requires-ruby-version-2-3-0-error/58776603#58776603